# JMeter and https

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter

I am trying to setup JMeter to test Web services running on Weblogic. The web service is served with `https`. When I run my tests on Weblogic console I get:

```
<13 May.2014 07.36 CEST> <Warning> <Security> <BEA-090476> <Invalid/unknown SSL header was received from peer myname.company.com - 192.168.0.1 during SSL handshake.>
```

I guess I need to set up something on Jmeter side. I dont exactly know what and how. Any tips?

On Jmeter website:

> To test a web server using SSL encryption (HTTPS), JMeter requires
>   that an *implementation of SSL* be provided, as is the case with Sun
>   Java 1.4 and above. If your version of Java does not include SSL
>   support, then it is possible to add an external implementation.
>   Include the necessary encryption packages in JMeter's classpath .
>   Also, update system.properties to register the SSL Provider.

Running on Windows 7, how do I find out which ssl provider I need? How do I check if my java includes SSL? I have got JDK 6,7 and 8 and testing with the latest one, i.e. 8.

**UPDATE**

The previous error was because JMeter used SSLv2 and Weblogic does not support it. After changing it to SSLv3 in JMeter, I am getting this error:

```
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 received HANDSHAKE>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: ClientKeyExchange RSA>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RSA>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm MD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: false>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 received CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HMACMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HMACMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: false>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 received HANDSHAKE>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: Finished>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC, offset = 0, length = 1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HMACMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HMACMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 16>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.findContext(sock): 1208820522>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <activateNoRegister()>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLFilterImpl.activate(): activated: 628843687 1178840099>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <1921821916 read(offset=0, length=4080)>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: true>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord()>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord returns true>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 SSL3/TLS MAC>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <71030870 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 151>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <1921821916 read databufferLen 151>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <1921821916 read A returns 151>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <1921821916 read(offset=151, length=3929)>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: true>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord()>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord returns false 1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <1921821916 Rethrowing InterruptedIOException>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.findContext(sock): 1208820522>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <activateNoRegister()>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLFilterImpl.activate(): activated: 628843687 492945567>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <1921821916 read(offset=151, length=3929)>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: true>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord()>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <hasSSLRecord returns false 1>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <1921821916 Rethrowing InterruptedIOException>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 0, length = 171>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 6, length = 923>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <NEW ALERT with Severity: WARNING, Type: 0
java.lang.Exception: New alert stack
        at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.closeWriteHandler(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.close(Unknown Source)
        at javax.net.ssl.impl.SSLSocketImpl.close(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.closeSocket(SocketMuxer.java:509)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.closeSocket(SocketMuxer.java:492)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.cleanupSocket(SocketMuxer.java:876)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverExceptionAndCleanup(SocketMuxer.java:833)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverEndOfStream(SocketMuxer.java:761)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.VirtualConnection.close(VirtualConnection.java:337)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.send(ServletResponseImpl.java:1574)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1498)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write ALERT, offset = 0, length = 2>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <close(): 1921821916>
<13.mai.2014 kl 10.19 CEST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.removeContext(ctx): 213906047>
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure JMeter to use SSLv3:

```
https.default.protocol=SSLv3
```

Additionally, make sure Weblogic uses SSL implementation in JDK:

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.SSLSocketFactoryImpl -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dweblogic.wsee.client.ssl.usejdk=true
```